# Cancel a script if directed to that page from a specific URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this bit of code to redirect to a mobile site if the

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 800) {
window.location = "http://mymobilesite.com ";
}
//-->
</script>
```

I want to cancel the above script if I am direct to the page form a speific URL, something like:

```
if (document.referrer !== "http://mymobilesite.com") {

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: And why doesn't your example work? It seems like that should be just fine.

Comment: I think because it is already being told to direct to the mobile version before it is able to run the document.referrer. I need something that says to redirect if the resolutions is less than 800 but not if the user arrived at this site from the specified URL.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not understanding your need, you want to cancel the script, if you are redirected from spcific site. for this, the below will work.

```
if (window.location.origin !== "http://mymobilesite.com") {
  // do something
}
```

This does not include any query string, only the url of the website including http/https .

Comment: window.location.origin is not a good idea since it's not supported on Legacy browsers, please read the documentation on MDN Web API, regarding "Window.location" for further information.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to redirect visitors to two different Web Address based on two main categories:
1) Mobile/Tablet
2) Desktops

There are better ways of doing that by using third-party JS plugins to detect visitors device. however, if you still insist on redirecting visitors by window width, please use the code below:

```
if (window.location.href !== "http://exception-url.com") {
    if (screen.width <= 800) {
        window.location.href = "http://redirected-url.com";
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work and is causing the page to continuously loop